# docker container running on EC2 with dynamic ip address

Tags: bash, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

as an assignment i had to create a gitlab container running on an ec2 (t3a.Xlarge if it matters). since i'm a cheap bastard, i don't want to buy a static ip from aws, but then - in order to run my container - everytime i'm using my container using the:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

command, i have to change my ip address according to the EC2 public ip address. for that matter, once starting my EC2 i'm getting a public ip address, copying it into the docker-compose-file.yml file (under the field of "hostname" and "external_url") and then fire up the docker-compose up -d command.

i'm trying to automate it by doing the following:

1. creating an environment variable with the value of: "curl ifconfig.me" (to get my public address).
2. in the compose file, i'm calling that env. var. to those 2 fields as mentioned above.
3. upon running the compose file - i'm getting an error. something is not going right as supposed to.
   i'm uploading here the compose file. this file is in accordance to the instructions as mentioned in the GitLab official website:
   [GitLab official instruction](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html)

and also my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest'
    restart: always
    container_name: 'gitlab-prvt'
    environment:
      - IpI
    hostname: IpI
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url $(IpI)
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2222
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '2222:22'
    volumes:
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '$GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
    shm_size: '256m'
```

(my env. var. is called IpI)
can anyone point me to how to make it work, please?

Comment: Can you set up a Route 53 DNS name, pointing at your instance's dynamic IP address?  That would give you a consistent external name even if the IP address changes when you recreate the instance.  (The container `hostname:` is all but meaningless and I expect you can safely delete it.)

Comment: not quite sure i understood you, @DavidMaze